# Are these two $3\times 3$ matrices similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is $A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$
and $B = \begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$ similar? Please justify your answer.

So far what I've done is to check rank, det, trace, and characteristic polynomial to maybe disprove it but all of them are the same so I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: How about minimal polynomial?

Comment: or its rational form?

Comment: Any thoughts about the answers that have been posted, confused?

Answer (score 6):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar, $A-I$ and $B-I$ must be similar too, which means that they must have the same rank. This is not the case here, thus $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: Nice shortcut!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

These are matrices in Jordan normal form. This is a representative  of the similarity class. Thus these matrices are not similar. For example $A$ has two independent eigenvectors to the eigenvalue $1$ whereas $B$ has only one.

Comment: I suspect that if OP were conversant with Jordan normal form, then OP would not have posted the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Then that is exactly what op need to learn. Good thing I explained it in my answer.

Comment: So, you consider that your answer explains how to distinguish between matrices that are, and are not, in Jordan normal form?

Comment: +1 Hooray a totally different approach via a different insight! God bless variety of answers! It’s great that our users here don’t discourage such answers because the original poster merely might not be totally ready for them yet. And it’s also wonderful that they never made prequels to the original Star Wars movies...

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the sarcasm, this site need more of that.

Comment: @rschwieb, I'm quite happy with answers OP is not ready for, so long as it's made clear to OP that he's not expected at this stage to understand them. When no such warning is given, OP might come to the conclusion that he is expected to understand the answer, which will make him feel worse than he already feels for being unable to answer the question that brought him here. I think one wants to show a little consideration for OP.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How do you know what op thinks or knows ? No more than I. Maybe op knows it maybe he doesnt. OP will comment or not if he wishes.

Comment: I can't be certain about what OP knows. But when someone posts two matrices that are in Jordan normal form, and asks whether they are similar, I don't think it's much of a stretch to conjecture that he's not conversant with Jordan normal form.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Maybe he knows but does not understand how they work yet.

Comment: Maybe. But if you had to bet on it, which way would you bet?

Comment: @GerryMyerson My point is that YOU do not KNOW.

Comment: My point is, when we don't know, we make the most likely guess – or, we seek out more information. We don't make the least likely guess.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, we wait to see if OP wants to represent himself in the conversation, and in the meantime we get a life.